# How to delete everything after the cursor

Tags: cursor-motions

Say the cursor is `[]`:

```
A very intelligent turtle
Found programming [U]NIX a hurdle
```

I want to achieve the same thing as `l D` in one go:

```
A very intelligent turtle
Found programming [U]
```

Is there any shortcut for this? I'd prefer a one keystroke solution, but would also like to note alternative motions.

Similar in title but not in question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784189/delete-everything-after-the-cursor-or-delete-everything-after-the-current-word

[2.22.22]:
What if you're in insert mode? Say the cursor is now `|`:

```
A very intelligent turtle
Found programming U|NIX a hurdle
```

What I tend to do here is either `ESC l D` or `SPC ESC D`.

Answer (score 1):

For a single keystroke I think your only option is a `nnoremap s lD` or something like that.